# what is the use of expiration_intent if I want to check the user in-app subscription is expired or not?

Tags: in-app-purchase, subscription

I am currently using sandbox and server to validate my receipt. when it come to handling the subscriptions expired or cancelled , I have to check the flags.  Would you please tell me how to handle these 2 cases with respect of the flags?

```
"pending_renewal_info": [
     {
      "expiration_intent": "1",  (cancelled subscription)
      "auto_renew_product_id": “product_ name”,
      "original_transaction_id": “11111111111111111”,
      "is_in_billing_retry_period": "0",
      "product_id": “product_name”,
      "auto_renew_status": "0"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expiration_intent` is the reason for the subscription expiration. If this field is present, it means the subscription has expired. You can also check the `expires_date` to determine when it expired.

> This key is only present for a receipt containing an expired auto-renewable subscription. You can use this value to decide whether to display appropriate messaging in your app for customers to resubscribe.
>
> “1” - Customer canceled their subscription.
>
> “2” - Billing error; for example customer’s payment information was no
>   longer valid.
>
> “3” - Customer did not agree to a recent price increase.
>
> “4” - Product was not available for purchase at the time of renewal.
>
> “5” - Unknown error.

Comment: That means either `expiration_intent`  or `expires_date` can check on whether my auto-renewable subscription is expired or not? I currently fetch the latest receipt info and get  `expires_date` for checking. Is that correct to ignore the `auto_renew_status` as well ?

Comment: Correct, checking `expires_date` will work and you'll know exactly when you should remove access. The `auto_renew_status` will let you know if the subscription is set to renew at the end of the period but has nothing to do with whether the user currently has access or not.

Comment: Would `is_trial_period`  be changed from `true` to `false` if  the trial period expires  ?

Comment: `is_trial_period` would be false if the user is in a paid renewal period. I'm not sure if it changes for expired trials or not.